# Passing List Of System.Data.Linq.ModifiedMemberInfo to a function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create an audit function like so:

```
public bool recordHeaderChanges(List<System.Data.Linq.ModifiedMemberInfo> mmi, string username)
    {
        var auditList = new List<data.tblVendorPackingSlipHeaderAudit>();

        foreach (var mm in mmi)
        {
            var nAudit = new data.tblVendorPackingSlipHeaderAudit()
            {
                username = username,
                dateTime = DateTime.Now,
                field = mm.Member.Name,
                OldVaue = mm.OriginalValue != null ? mm.OriginalValue.ToString() : null,
                NewValue = mm.CurrentValue != null ? mm.CurrentValue.ToString() : null

            };

            auditList.Add(nAudit);
        }

        CustomClasses.DataTableHelper.BulkCopyToDatabase(auditList, "tblVendorPackingSlipHeaderAudit", db);

        return true;
    }
```

And I invoke it like so:

```
var changes = db.tblVendorPackingSlipHeaders.GetModifiedMembers(dbDoc).ToList();
recordHeaderChanges(changes, User.Identity.Name)
```

The problem is that everything in ModifiedMemberInfo object is null when passed as parameter.

Is this even possible?

Comment: How are you getting that list of `changes`?

Comment: Sorry about that, `var changes = db.tblVendorPackingSlipHeaders.GetModifiedMembers(dbDoc).ToList();'